# Calculating time spent on a site in JS

Tags: javascript

I require user time spent on a website or page from window load to window unload.

I am trying the below code to calculate user time spent on a website, it’s a basic calculation comparing the start of page load versus when the 'beforeunload' event occurs, but in many cases this does not give accurate results for session length, as well as the sessions are getting missed out.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event)
    {
        // Ensure the current interaction is saved 
        newrelic.interaction().save();
        var navStartTime = window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
        var unloadTime = Date.now();
        var timeOnPage = unloadTime - navStartTime;
        var durationTimeoutReached = false;

        // Limit the page session to 30 minutes (1800000 milliseconds). 30-minute timeout is based on analytics standards.
        
        if (timeOnPage > 1800000)
        {
          durationTimeoutReached = true;
          timeOnPage = 1800000;
        }

        // Custom value passed to New Relic using API
        newrelic.setCustomAttribute('timeOnPage', timeOnPage);
        newrelic.setCustomAttribute('durationTimeoutReached', durationTimeoutReached);
    });
 
    function getCookie(cookieName) 
        {
          var name = cookieName + "=";
          var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
          var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
          for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) 
          {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
            {
              c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) 
            {
              return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
          }
          return "";
        }

        function generateId() 
        {
            return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
            var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
            return v.toString(16);
            })
        }

        function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, maxAge) 
        {
            document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + "; max-age=" + maxAge * 60 + "; path=/";
        }

        function setNrAttributes(name, value) 
        {
            newrelic.setCustomAttribute(name, value);
            newrelic.interaction().setAttribute(name, value);
        }

        function recordActivity() 
        {
            activityRecorded = true;
        }

        function keepSessionCurrent() 
        {
            // Check for existing session ID
            sessionId = getCookie("nr-user-session");

            if (sessionId != '') {
            // If a cookie with session ID already exists, set custom attributes using it
            // and then reset the cookie expiration timer

            setNrAttributes('userSessionID', sessionId);
            setCookie('nr-user-session', sessionId, timeoutMinutes);
            } else {
            // If no cookie with session ID exists, generate a new ID and then create 
            // the cookie to store it 
            sessionId = generateId();
            setNrAttributes('userSessionID', sessionId);
            setCookie('nr-user-session', sessionId, timeoutMinutes);
            }
        }

            if (typeof newrelic !== 'undefined')
            {
                if (navigator.cookieEnabled) 
                {
                    var timeoutMinutes = 30;
                    var activityRecorded = false;
                    var sessionId = '';

                    // When page first loads, check session cookie and update if necessary
                    keepSessionCurrent(); 

                    // Set up event listeners to track user activity 
                    var events = ['click', 'mousedown', 'mousemove', 'keypress', 'scroll', 'touchstart'];
                    events.forEach(function(name) {
                    document.addEventListener(name, recordActivity, true); 
                    }); 

                    // Each minute, check if activity has occurred and reset cookie expiration if so
                    var updateCycle = setInterval(function() {
                    if (activityRecorded == true) {
                    keepSessionCurrent();
                    activityRecorded = false;
                    }
                    }, 60000);
                } 
                else
                {
                setNrAttributes('userSessionID', 'Unable to set cookie');
                }
            }
```

Comment: From the MDN page for [`beforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event): "*The beforeunload event suffers from some problems [...] It is not reliably fired, especially on mobile platforms.*" Reliability is not exactly something this event provides, and it's not surprising that "*sessions are getting missed out*". The linked MDN page recommends using `visibilitychange` instead, if you need reliability of the event being fired.

Comment: I'd suggest a different approach: send to the server an AJAX request every 15-30 seconds and let the server calculate the time spent on the page.